# Amonium perchlorate

Tags: precipitation

I want to make **amonium perchlorate**, having amonium chlorate. If I have a solution of **sodium chlorate** and I add amonium chlorate, will precipitate into amonium perchlorate? Or it is with a solution of **sodium perchlorate**?

Comment: Chlorate won't magically transform to perchlorate.

Comment: > having amonium chlorate | And you are still in one piece? How that?

Comment: Ammonium chlorate becomes nonexplosive when "ammonium" is spelled with only two rather than three "m"s.  -1.

Comment: Why would you want the sodium perchlorate?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: Ammonium chlorate is a **unstable oxidizers and decomposes violently**. Handle with care. Ammonium perchlorate is also known for its **toxicity**. You should have enough laboaratory experience for handling such chemicals.

---

If you think that

$$\ce{chlorate + chlorate -> perchlorate}$$

then you are wrong. There is no common ion effect occuring. You will need a perchlorate salt and an ammonium salt that have a  displacement reaction and precipitate ammonium perchlorate. This reaction will suffice

$$\ce{MClO4 + NH4Cl -> NH4ClO4 + MCl ~~~~~~~~~~~ M = Na,K}$$

Or even electrolysis of a perchlorate salt. According to [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3288560):

> 1. Ammonium perchlorate is generally produced by a series of steps which include the electrolysis of an aqueous sodium chloride solution
>      to sodium chlorate, which is in turn electrolytically converted to
>      sodium perchlorate. The sodium perchlorate is then reacted with
>      ammonium and chloride ions to produce ammonium perchlorate and the
>      by-product, sodium chloride.
> 2. reacting the sodium perchlorate with ammonium chloride
> 3. sodium perchlorate might be reacted with ammonia gas in the presence of carbon dioxide, to produce ammonium perchlorate. This
>      alternative procedure has been generally unsuccessful because of the
>      difiiculty of separating the resulting sodium bicarbonate from the
>      product, ammonium perchlorate.

Process 2 is described in [another patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3502430). Read more to know the purification and the precautions needed.

> ... the reaction is carried out by mixing aqueous solutions of the
>   reactants. The concentrations of the solutions are such that the
>   resultant ammonium perchlorate precipitates out of the aqueous medium.
>   The ammonium perchlorate crystals recovered therefrom contain 5% to by
>   weight of the mother liquor. The product is usually contaminated with
>   the Water soluble alkali salt, the byproduct of the reaction, in the
>   mother liquor.

---

Note: direct electrolysis of ammonium chlorate would not yield ammonium perchlorate as there would be chlorate contamination. In fact, there should be no chlorate as reactants. ([Here](http://www.chlorates.exrockets.com/nh4clo4.html))